# Errors may have originated from an input operation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Estoy entrenando una red en Keras y tengo el siguiente error:
Errors may have originated from an input operation.

Y no consigo entender ni encontrar dónde se encuentra el error.

Mi modelo es una red recurrente con capas LSTM:

```
model2 = keras.Sequential([
keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen),
keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences= True)),
keras.layers.LSTM (64, dropout = 0.2, recurrent_dropout = 0.2, return_sequences = True),
keras.layers.LSTM (128, dropout = 0.2, recurrent_dropout = 0.2, return_sequences = True),
keras.layers.LSTM (256, dropout = 0.2, recurrent_dropout = 0.2, return_sequences = True),
keras.layers.LSTM (64, dropout = 0.2, recurrent_dropout = 0.2),
keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')])
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.01)
model2.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
history2 = model2.fit(training_X, training_y, epochs = 60, validation_data=[test_X, test_y],batch_size= 32)
```

Por otro lado, mi conjunto de datos son unos word embeddings que se encuentran en un unos numpy arrays.

Todas las secuencias tienen la misma longitud y se ha hecho un padding.

```
def padding(preguntas, maxm):
    padded = pad_sequences(preguntas, maxlen = maxm, padding = padding_type, truncating = trunc_type)
    return padded
```

Este es el numpy del training_X

```
array([[   450,   1184, 894844, ...,      0,      0,      0],
       [  2251,     27,    657, ...,      0,      0,      0],
       [   680,   9383,   1184, ...,      0,      0,      0],
       ...,
       [  3736,    624, 894844, ...,      0,      0,      0],
       [  1378,     54,    894, ...,      0,      0,      0],
       [   727,    624, 894844, ...,      0,      0,      0]], dtype=int32)
```

Esta es la traza completa del error

```
Epoch 1/60

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-317-c4f377fad6df> in <module>
----> 1 history2 = model2.fit(training_X, training_y, epochs = 60, validation_data=[test_X, test_y], batch_size= 32)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    805       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    806       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 807       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    808     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    809       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2827     with self._lock:
   2828       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2829     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2830 
   2831   @property

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs, cancellation_manager)
   1846                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))],
   1847         captured_inputs=self.captured_inputs,
-> 1848         cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
   1849 
   1850   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1922       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1923       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1924           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1925     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1926         args,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    548               inputs=args,
    549               attrs=attrs,
--> 550               ctx=ctx)
    551         else:
    552           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError:  indices[29,0] = 894845 is not in [0, 2327)
     [[node sequential_7/embedding_10/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-289-a651e93bc0ed>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_20617]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential_7/embedding_10/embedding_lookup:
 sequential_7/embedding_10/embedding_lookup/14840 (defined at /home/roberto/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py:112)

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Parece ser que el error está en la entrada de datos, pero he revisado los conjuntos de datos y confirmado que todos tienen la misma longitud, y todos los datos dentro de los arrays son enteros. Qué más podría ser? A alguien se le ocurre alguna idea sobre dónde puede estar el error?

Os agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has creado incorrectamente la capa `embedding()` donde se ve el error es en esta linea de la traza de error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  indices[29,0] = 894845 is not in [0, 2327)
```

Esa linea te está diciendo que le has indicado que tu número de palabras máximo es 2327 y sin embargo, tienes una palabra con el indice 894849, es decir hay dos opciones:

1. Tu parámetro `vocab_size` es incorrecto, porque realmente tu corpus tiene 894849 palabras y tu le has indicado a la capa que tiene 2327
2. Tu preprocesado de palabras es incorrecto y la variable `training_X` le está entregando la palabra 894845 cuando en realidad tu solo quieres tener como máximo 2327.

Comment: Gracias tienes razón. El número de palabras es 2327, pero la palabra mayor está representado por un embedding con el int 894849 por lo que la red esperaba que al tener ese int, hay un número de palabras iguales a esa cantidad.